# SharePoint OneDrive & CIFS

Tags: sharepoint, network-share, file-sharing

I'm working on a project that includes moving users away from their network shared folder to SharePoint. Is there any option to have a user's SharePoint OneDrive cloud space live inside their existing network share? In this way, a user'S CIFS network mount is available as a network mount & via the SharePoint website.

Same thing, reworded - Can a SharePoint user's personal file space use an existing network mount as the underlying storage?

All guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I'd probably look at groups rather than onedrive if the purpose is to share items.

Answer (score 0):

No and no. Migrate all of the appropriate content into SharePoint/OneDrive. Use the OneDrive next gen sync client (included in Win 10 and a download for earlier OSes) to synchronize content from SharePoint/OneDrive as required to their assigned computer.

Microsoft has no solutions available that are designed to perform synchronization from SharePoint/OneDrive to a file share for general use.